# Two questions related to virtual functions

Tags: c++

I was reading this articles , was at this heading
[Inheritance of Base-class vPtrs](http://progtutorials.tripod.com/cpp2.htm#_Toc50821294) , but couldn't understand what did he mean in this para :

"However, due to multiple inheritance, a class may indirectly inherit from many classes. If we decide to merge the vtables of all the base classes into one, the vtable may become very big. ***To avoid this, instead of discarding the vPtrs and vtables of all base classes and merging all vtables into one, the compiler only does it to all the FIRST base classes, and retains the vPtrs and vtables of all the subsequent base classes and their base classes***."

***In other words, in an object’s memory footprint, you can find the vPtrs of all its base classes all through the hierarchy, except for all the “first-borns”**.* "

Can anyone please explain this para in simple understandable form.

Another question ,please have look at this answer :
[Follow this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006766/how-to-use-the-vtable-to-determine-class-type/3006893#3006893)

now code of interest  `(*(foo)((void**)(((void**)(&a))[0]))[1])();` , can anyone tell what is going on? , specially why does this doing exactly in c++`(void**)(&a)` . i know this is casting but `&a` returns the address of vptr (in the above question link 2) whose type is void* .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to your first question, I don't really follow what the
quoted passage is getting at; it actually sounds like the author doesn't
really understand how vtables work (or hasn't thought about it in
detail).  It's important to realize that when we speak of
“merging” the base and the derived classes' vtables, we are
talking about making the base class vtable a prefix of the derived class
table; the base class vtable must start at the start of the derived
class vtable for this to work; the offset of the vptr in both the base
and the derived must be identical (almost always 0, in practice), and
the base class must be placed at the very beginning of the derived.  And
of course, it's only possible to fulfil those conditions for one base
class.  (Most compilers will use the first non-virtual base appearing in
a left to right scan of the code.)

With regards to the expression, it's completely undefined behavior, and
will not work with some compilers.  Or may or may not work, depending on
the level of optimization.  And the `void*` in it is being used as a
placeholder for any number of pointer types (including, probably,
pointer to function types).  If we take the inner-most part, we're
saying that `&a` is a pointer to (1 or more) `void*`.  This pointer is
then dereferenced (`(X)[0]` is the same as `*(X)`, so
`(((void**)(&a))[0])` is the same as `*(void**)(&a)`.  (The `[0]`
notation suggests that there might be more values behind this one; i.e.
that `[1]`, etc. might also be valid.  That's not the case here.)  This
results in a `void*`, which is then cast to a `void**` and once again
dereferenced, this time really using an index (since it is hopefully
into an array); the result of this dereferencing is converted to a `foo`
(a pointer to a function), which is then dereferenced and the function
is called without any arguments.

None of this will actually work.  It makes a number of suppositions
which are not always, or in some cases even generally, true:

- The offset of the vptr in an object is 0.  (This one is generally true.)
- The vptr itself has the same size as a `void*`.  (This is almost always true, and required by Posix.)
- The vtable itself is an array of pointers to functions, and that
  pointers to functions have the same size as a `void*`.  And while
  it's true that pointers to functions do often have the same size as
  `void*` (again, Posix requires it, and it's also true under Windows),
  it's hard to imagine an implementation which would work if the vtable
  were just an array of pointers to functions.
- That the function called doesn't actually use the this pointer:
  this is only true in exceptional cases.

He apparently is using VC++ (based on the `__thiscall`, which is a
Microsoft'ism), and I've only analysed the layout of Sun CC, which is
definitely different.  (And Sun CC and g++ are also very
different—for that matter, Sun CC 3.1, Sun CC 4.0 and Sun CC 5.0
are all different.)

Unless you're actually writing a compiler, I'd ignore all of this.  And
I'd certainly ignore the expression you quote.

Comment: vptrs having the same size as void * is also required under windows for COM compatibility.

Comment: what i think is , since `&a` will return address to its first data @James : member (which is object's address i know)  which is pointer to void* i.e vptr (pointing to vtable). so type of &a doesn't becomes type void** ?. see this : ideone.com/Dfnon. I'm so confused right now. let me know what i think is right?

Comment: @Mr. Anubis `&a` returns the address of the object.  Unless the object type is a POD (not the case), this is not necessarily the same as the address of its first data; in practice, it will be the address where the vptr is located.  And the cast doesn't make `&a` become `void**`; it makes the compiler treat it as if it were a `void*`.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual function calls are commonly implemented using a [virtual method table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table). Compilers typically create one such table for each class in your program, and give each object a pointer to the virtual table that corresponds to its class when the object is instantiated (this pointer is referred to as `vptr`). This way, the object "knows" exactly which function to call when you call a virtual method regardless of its static type.

As I mentioned above, normally each class gets its own virtual method table. The paragraph you cite says that if a class derives from e.g. 5 base classes, each of which also derives from 5 other classes, then the virtual table for this class should end up being a merged version of all 25 virtual tables of the base classes. This would be kind of wasteful, so the compiler might decide to only merge the 5 virtual tables from the "immediate" base classes into the derived class's virtual table, and keep the `vptr`s to the other 20 virtual tables stored as a hidden member inside the class (which would now have 21 `vptr`s total).

The benefit in doing this is that you don't need to reserve memory repeating the same information every time a class with a virtual table is derived from. The downside is that you complicate the implementation (e.g. when calling a virtual method, the compiler now has to somehow figure out which one of the `vptr`s points to the table that tells it which method to call).

Regarding the second question, I 'm not sure what exactly you are asking. This code assumes that the `vptr` is the very first item in the memory layout of object of that class (which is practically true often, but *a horrible hack since nowhere does it say that virtual methods are even implemented using a virtual table*; there might *not even be* a `vptr`), fetches the second item from the table (which is a pointer to a member function of the class) and runs it.

Expect fireworks if even the slightest thing goes wrong (e.g.: there was no `vptr`, the `vptr`'s structure is not what the person who wrote the code expected, a later version of the compiler decides to change how it stores the virtual table, the method pointed to has a different signature, etc etc etc).

**Update (addressing the comments)**:

Let's say we have

```
class Child : Mom, Dad {};

class Mom : GrandMom1, GrandDad1 {};

class Dad : GrandMom2, GrandDad2 {};
```

In this case, `Mom` and `Dad` are the immediate base classes ("first-born", but the term is misleading).

Comment: what does the para mean when it says "first borns" though?

Comment: from what i could make of the paragraph, i think first-born refers to the immediate parent classes, strangely; i was guessing the idea was they are the first-born in terms of what additional classes needed to be added on compiling.

Answer (score 2):

If Derived inherits from Base, its vtable will extend Base's. Now, if it also inherits Base2, its vtable will not include Base2's - Base2's part will retain its vtable (updated with Derived virtual functions, if they override Base2's).

```
  Base members      Base2 members    Derived members
+--+------------+----+------------+------------------+
 |                |
 V                V
Derived + Base   Base2 vtable  
vtable
```

To make the second question easier to understand, and since I enjoy drawing with fixed width font... here's the memory layout of `a`. For a full explanation about that expression, see James Kanze's answer.

```
        +---+----------+
a:      | | |    A     |
        +-+-+----------+
          |
          V
vtable: +---+
        | --+--> f2()
        +---+
        | --+--> f3()
        +---+
```

HTH...

Comment: don't you think your line `casting &a to a void* will point you to the first element of the virtual table` is wrong? , since `&a` will return address to its first elements which is which is pointer to void* (pointing to vtable) . see this : http://www.ideone.com/Dfnon. I'm so confused right now , please help with illustrated example Thanks

Comment: Casting `&a` to a `void*` will **not** change what it points to in memory; it will still point to the start of `a`.  It's casting it to a `void**`, then dereferencing, which gets the vptr (if everything goes right, and all of the assumptions hold, and the compiler doesn't do funny optimizations, etc., etc.).

Comment: @James : my mind is crying and i am unable to understand what you are saying , please give answer point to point which i can understand . tell me what is it , what intention to do it , what does it do exactly `(void**)&a`

Comment: @Mr.Anubis, @James Kanze, looking at it now, I don't know how that void* got there... I've scrapped that part of my answer, since James'es is better anyway.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis, I've added a drawing of `a`'s memory layout. Hope this somewhat helps your mind stop crying... :-)

Comment: @eran That's nice. About the only thing to note is in the vtable: it generally also contains an entry pointing to the RTTI information, and depending on the implementation, the pointers to the functions are more than just a pointer.  There must be some way of adjusting the this pointer as well.  (Think of having a `Base2*`, and calling a function overridden in `Derived`.)

Comment: @James : read your twice , now understood everything .  thanks a lot to you and eran.

Comment: @James Kanze, AFAIK the _common_ way to adjust `this` is by using thunks, but adding that to the picture would probably have increased the poor OP's headache...

Comment: @eran Thunks are one common solution. I seem to recall extra information even when thunks were present (related to virtual bases), but a dump on g++ doesn't seem to show it today.  But I'm not too sure.  A look at the generated code shows that the vptr in g++ actually points to somewhere in the middle of the vtable: the function addresses follow, but various RTTI, including information concerning the offset of the virtual base, precedes.

Answer (score 0):

for question 1:
i think the paragraph is just saying that the vtables aren't actually merged into one and stored in the memory allocation of the class that is multiply deriving; but that the vtables of the base classes beyond the first base classes are used by reference.

in other words; if you have Rose which derives from Flower which derives from Plant then Rose only incorporates Flower's vtable directly, but uses of Plant's vtable are done by calling them from Plant's vtable.
)

for question 2:
i am not so great at doing these in my head, i would have to just start breaking it down into manageable chunks to understand.

first i would tabify it like so:

```
(
  *(foo)
  (
    (void**)
    (
      ((void**)(&a))[0]
    )
  )
  [1]
)
();
```

then,

Step 1:

`((void**)(&a))[0]`

we know `(X)[0]` = `*X`

let `X` = `(void**)&a`

`X[0]` = `((void**)&a)[0]` = `(void*)a`

now replace:

```
(
  *(foo)
  (
    (void**)
    (
      (void*)(a)
    )
  )
  [1]
)
();
```

Step 2:

`(void**)((void*)(a))` = `(void**)(void*)a = (void**)a`

```
(
  *(foo)
  (
    (void**)a
  )
  [1]
)
();
```

Step 3:

so it looks like we are left with a function pointer

`(foo)((void**)a)[1]` = `(foo)((void*)(a+1))`

or, what looks like a void* to function at position (a+1), of type foo...

i think that's at least close to right :) function pointers always give me problems. ;)

Comment: please what does this line means `(void**)(&a)`

Comment: well, taken by itself, it means take the address of "a" and cast it to a pointer to void*... another way: "a" is being treated as if it holds a void*, so taking the address of a void* gives you a void**.

Comment: or: an int* is a pointer to int; an int** is a pointer to a pointer to int.  "void" is special when used in a pointer type, void* is a pointer to an unspecified/unknown type.  so, a void** is just a pointer to a pointer to some unknown type.  so, from (void**)(&a) we can see that we're treating "a" as a pointer to some unknown type.  if it helps: (void**)(&a) is equivalent to (void**)&a and also &((void*)a).